# How to pass parameter in JsonArrayRequest from which value fetch from database based on given parameter

Tags: java, android, android-volley

How to pass parameter in `JsonArrayRequest` for fetching result based on parameter like fetch result based on email

```
ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listshow);
final List<String> listItem = new ArrayList<>();
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listItem);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(showdetails.this);

JsonArrayRequest objectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

        //this loop is used to fetch data from object and displayed on list view
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject obj1 = response.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = obj1.getString("name");
                String phone = obj1.getString("phone");

                //insert data on listview
                listItem.add("Name :" + name + "\nPhone" + phone);

                //this line is used for aknowledgement that adapter hold one data
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
});
requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
return super.hashCode();
    '''
```

Comment: Improve readability

Comment: you are fetching data from server right?

Comment: Yes I fetch data from server